# Group join with many to one in one row

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, one-to-many, relation

I would love some help. I'd like to join a one-to-many database and show all the info from one row in table 'post' with it's related meta (many). I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Database called post:

```
ID      Title
1       Hello world
2       Yeah buddy
3       This is a test
```

Database called meta:

```
ID      postID     Value
1       1          Testing testing
2       1          This is a value
3       2          Testing 123 testing
4       2          This is a value 23
5       3          Testing testing test
6       3          This is a value yeah
```

I would like to group the results for my query as follows:

```
1       Hello world        Testing testing        This is a value
2       Yeah buddy         Testing 123 testing    This is a value 23
3       This is a test     Testing testing test   This is a value yeah
```

MySQL Query (so far):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.title, m.*
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN meta m ON p.ID = m.postID
GROUP BY p.title
```

Only the output given is:

```
1       Hello world        Testing testing       
2       Yeah buddy         Testing 123 testing    
3       This is a test     Testing testing test
```

Which is really frustrating because I would like to show all the related fields, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. It seems the 'Value'-column can't exist twice per row...

Can somebody please help (or point me in the right direction?)

Comment: Issues of data display are generally best handled at the presentation layer/application-level code (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array). If you're determined to solve this in MySQL, then I might suggest that proper DDLs be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work for you if values are combined?

```
SELECT p.title, group_concat(m.value separator ",") as values
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN meta m ON p.ID = m.postID
GROUP BY p.title
```